# Ccxt Binance API error: '"code":-1104,"msg":"Not all sent parameters were read'

Tags: node.js, binance, binance-api-client, ccxt

I'm working with a [CCXT](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt) hedge order in [Binance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binance) using [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js). Here's the code:

```
const ccxt = require('ccxt');

(async () => {
    const exchange = new ccxt.binance({
        apiKey: 'C7g1OwtPLTL5z1cUTNobdBC9TOlCZnM719v8mcqUSZc3PjCsRkBKzNMujyXboxDm',
        secret: 'YAwGUy8dJI5hfTgTZldaL0DaX0r9yQLJgZksWzdCa4rvKUcvp6lSDNRJ8kIdhJNK',

        
    });
    exchange.setSandboxMode(true);

    const symbol = 'BTC/USDT'
    const type = 'market'  
    const side = 'buy'
    const amount = 123.45 
    const price = 1543.21 

    const params = { 'positionSide': 'LONG' }

    const order = await exchange.createOrder(symbol, type, side, amount, undefined, params)
    console.log(order)

})()
```

But whenever I run it in the terminal, it always throws me this error:

```
BadRequest: binance {"code":-1104,"msg":"Not all sent parameters were read; read '9' parameter(s) but was sent '10'."}
    at binance.throwExactlyMatchedException (C:\Users\NGUYEN TUNG LAM\lapi\node_modules\ccxt\dist\cjs\src\base\Exchange.js:2799:19)
    at binance.handleErrors (C:\Users\NGUYEN TUNG LAM\lapi\node_modules\ccxt\dist\cjs\src\binance.js:7566:18)
    at C:\Users\NGUYEN TUNG LAM\lapi\node_modules\ccxt\dist\cjs\src\base\Exchange.js:761:51
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async binance.fetch2 (C:\Users\NGUYEN TUNG LAM\lapi\node_modules\ccxt\dist\cjs\src\base\Exchange.js:2441:16)
    at async binance.request (C:\Users\NGUYEN TUNG LAM\lapi\node_modules\ccxt\dist\cjs\src\binance.js:7596:26)
    at async binance.createOrder (C:\Users\NGUYEN TUNG LAM\lapi\node_modules\ccxt\dist\cjs\src\binance.js:4210:26)
    at async tick (C:\Users\NGUYEN TUNG LAM\lapi\lapi.js:61:19)
```

The problem here is the 'params' parameter, which is { 'positionSide': 'LONG' }. If I remove it, everything work just fine, but I want to place a hedge order, so I have to add that parameter. When I searched for the same problem, I saw that most people got this error by adding a parameter that does not exist in the exchange's API documentation, but the 'positionSide' parameter is included in Binance API documentation:

*[New Order (TRADE)](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/testnet/en/#new-order-trade)*

What's wrong here?